# Referência de objeto é necessária para o campo, o método ou a propriedade "notificationhub" não estática

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    //from here we will send notification message to client
    NotificationHub.SendNotification("João"); // <----- Aqui

    ....
}
```

**Hub:**

```
public void SendNotification(string who)
{
    string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
    {
        Clients.Client(connectionId).addNotification(name + ": " + "message");
    }
}
```

Erro da linha `NotificationHub.SendNotification(Who);` :

> Uma referência de objeto é necessária para o campo, o método ou a
>   propriedade "NotificationHub.SendNotification(string)" não estática

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. Exatamente o que diz na mensagem de erro, é necessário criar uma instância de `NotificationHub` para chamar o método `SendNotification()`. Isso porque o método é **não-estático**, ou seja, ele só pode ser acessado por uma instância da classe.

Dependendo do caso, será necessário uma instância específica, mas não tenho como falar sobre isso porque não há detalhes na pergunta.

```
NotificationHub notHub = new NotificationHub();
notHub.SendNotification("João");
```

Comment: @jubeno, só um detalhe, na classe hub, ocorre problema `Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'
` na linha `Clients.Client(connectionId).addNotification(who);` o que pode ser ?

Comment: Não é porque Clients.Client(connId) retorna null?

Comment: Salve numa variável isto e verifique se há algum valor

Comment: Está retornado como nulo, segue a imagem: https://postimg.org/image/wkgocwc5d/

Comment: Então. Você precisa achar a causa disso

Comment: Grande jbueno !,  fiz uma nova pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209573/valores-chegando-nulos-com-sqldep-onchange      caso voce souber responder, eu agradeço.

Comment: Opa, vou ler agora. Mesmo que eu saiba como resolver pode ser que não responda ainda (13% de bateria), mas vejo quando tiver mais "preparado"