# SqlDep_OnChange com SignalR não funciona

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

Segue código:

**NotificationHub : Hub**

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();

public void SendNotification(string who)
{
    foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
    {
        var result = Clients.Client(connectionId);

        Clients.Client(connectionId).addNotification(who);
    }
}
```

**Components.cs:**

```
void SqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{

    //from here we will send notification message to client
    NotificationHub notHub = new NotificationHub();
    notHub.SendNotification(Who);

    //...
}
```

**_Layout:**

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection.notificationHub;

    //signalr method for push server message to client
    connection.client.addNotification = function (who) {
        //send notification here
        console.info("Send Notification")
    };

    // Start hub
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("SignalR Started")
    });
});
```

Na classe `Hub`e na linha `var result = Clients.Client(connectionId);` está retornando alguns campos como nulo.

Segue imagem: https://postimg.org/image/wkgocwc5d/

O código a seguir funciona com a função `click` do jquery:

```
 $(function () {
        var connection = $.connection.notificationHub;

        //signalr method for push server message to client
        connection.client.addNotification = function (who) {
            //send notification here
            console.info("Send Notification")
        };

        // Start hub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#testeclick").click(function () {
                connection.server.sendNotification("User15248");
            });
            console.log("SignalR Started")
        });
    });
```

Segue o resultado após da função `click` do jquery: https://postimg.org/image/p8iwdzaaf/

A função `click` funciona perfeitamente. Só não consigo fazer ela funcionar com `SqlDep_OnChange` quando faz alteração de banco de dados.

A ideia é: Após de fazer um "update" no banco de dados, mostrar uma notificação para cliente com signalr.

Alguma solução ?

---

**UPDATE:** (Problema quase resolvido)

**NotificationHub : Hub**

```
public static void SendNotification(string who)
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
            {
                var result = context.Clients.Client(connectionId);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    result.addNotification(who);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Components.cs:**

```
void SqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{

    //from here we will send notification message to client
    NotificationHub.SendNotification("User1586");
    //...
}
```

*Problema quase foi resolvido, se tiver 50 usuários, ele manda a notificação 50 vezes para usuário "User1586". Se tiver 1000 usuários, manda 1000 vezes a notificação.*

Com problema dessa linha: `NotificationHub.SendNotification("User1586");`(passa várias vezes)

Comment: Quais campos, especificamente estão nulos?

Comment: @jbueno Connection, HubName and Invoker. Ou se preferir imagem: https://postimg.org/image/wkgocwc5d/

Comment: Parece que esse `_connections.GetConnections(who)` está retornando todos as conexões (de todos os usuários). Ou, o seu javascript aí está sendo executado inúmeras vezes para o mesmo client, assim criando várias conexões para um mesmo usuário.